# How do I create an "Open" and "Closed" indicator?

Tags: java, android

I have a MapView. Within this MapView I have MapOverlays. The MapOverlays have two icons plotted on the map. There is one GREEN and one RED. I want to make these into OPEN and CLOSED indicators.

I want to read a "time" (myTime for instance) that I have setted and check that with SystemTime to see if it is open or closed.

Pseudocode: IF myTime == SystemTime { shop indicator turns into GREEN marker } ELSE  { shop indicator turn into RED market }.

I have the timings for the two shops I want to add to the MapView.

How would I write this?

Here is an image for clarification:

[image]

```
public void mapOverlayItems() {

    // Creates a marker based on lat/long values on MapView

            // DIVIDER markerGREEN
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawableBar = getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.markergreen);
    mapOverlayBar = new MapOverlayActivity(drawableBar, mapView);


    GeoPoint sirius = new GeoPoint((int) (52.63274 * 1E6),
            (int) (-1.13145 * 1E6));
    OverlayItem siriusbaricon = new OverlayItem(sirius, "Sirius", "Bar");
    mapOverlayBar.addOverlay(siriusbaricon);

    mapOverlays.add(mapOverlayBar);
    mapView.invalidate();

  //DIVIDER markerRed

Drawable drawableBank = getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.markerred);
    mapOverlayBanks = new MapOverlayActivity(drawableBank, mapView);
    GeoPoint natwest = new GeoPoint((int) (52.63440 * 1E6),
            (int) (-1.1314 * 1E6));
    OverlayItem natwesticon = new OverlayItem(natwest, "Natwest", "Bank");
    mapOverlayBanks.addOverlay(natwesticon);
    mapOverlays.add(mapOverlayBanks);
    mapView.invalidate();
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: can paste code i will make changes?

Comment: Code pasted above. Thank you Agarwal for replying.

Comment: Just to add, for clarification if needed: I am using BalloonItemizedOverlay. If this helps at all.

Comment: you need to change the marker only?

Comment: Yes. However, each of the markers represent a "shop". The shop (let's say) is open: 12:00 and closed: 23:00. Between 12:00 & 23:00 I want it to have the GREEN marker indicating that store is OPEN. Else, I want marker to be RED to indicate that shop is CLOSED. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a marker for any point on the map by using the following code.

```
int lat = some number;
int lng = some number;

GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);

MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
List<Overlay> overlays = map.getOverlays();
overlays.add(new DrawableMapOverlay(this, point, R.drawable.mapmarker));
```

The last line actually puts the marker on the map. I would wrap that last line in an "if/else" statement so that you could choose your custom drawable. Hope this helps.